# Too many Activities in Android App. Any alternatives?

Tags: android

I am creating my first app. In this app, I have an expandable list with many items. When I select any of these items, I want several paragraphs to be displayed. Do I need to create an Activity for each of these items if text is the only thing I want displayed? I know that there has to be an easier way. I did create it like this at first and it seemed very bulky (30+ activities), so now I have it set up so that when an item is selected, the setContentView opens the corresponding layout with the text that needs to be displayed. This works but there is a catch, whenever I hit the back button, it takes me back to my main activity class and not my expandable list class. I want the user to be able to go back and select something else from the list. Any guidance as to what I need to do would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating string resources for each item you would like to display, then creating one activity with a TextView. Then, instead of creating new intents for each activity, create an intent that goes to the new activity, and add an extra that contains the text for the TextView. For example:

Activity1:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ParagraphView.class);
        intent.putExtra("textData", getResources().getString(R.string.myText));
        getBaseContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In the onCreate of the viewer, add this to get your TextView:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String textData = intent.getStringExtra("text");
```

Now, we need to write the text into the TextView:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
tv.setText(textData);
```

All you have to to is set up your string resources and button click listeners. You may consider this easier than having lots of activities (it's definitely easier to manage entries this way) but does require a bit of setup.

Edit: Thanks to @ianhanniballake for pointing out a much better way (I don't even know what I was thinking at the time...)

Edit2: Wow, I REALLY messed up my code. (Hopefully) Fixed now

Comment: This code doesn't actually work you know? You'd need to use [Resources.getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) at the very least to convert strings into proper resource ids. Why not just pass in R.string.paragraphId (or even getString(R.string.paragraphId) if you want)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Good point about passing the resource right through the intent. (Guess I'm a little too tired to think properly tonight...) Will update that.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question and pointing me in the right direction. I'll try this out.